# Simple Ajax Uploader Plugin Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, file-upload, google-chrome-devtools

We're using the javascript plugin Simple-ajax-uploader to upload files on your web site and it suddenly stopped working today (09/05/2019).
The upload div/button can't be clicked on anymore.

This is happening on our site and even on the [official plugin site](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader). 
This is only happening on Chrome and only on computers where Chrome has been closed and restarted today.

We found out [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/09/devtools) indicating that Chrome Dev tools have just been updated today but our version of Chrome hasn't changed since the restart (76.0.3809.132). However the restart definitely triggered the bug so something happened there. But what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem here found this morning.

Quick jQuery fix...

```
$('input[type=file]').css('position','relative');
```

Comment: Plugin maintainer here. I strongly recommend upgrading to version 2.6.5 instead of using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Issue has been fixed with version 2.6.5 of the plugin. Ignore the below.

<strike>Plugin maintainer here. A short term fix is to remove or comment out [line 2002](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader/blob/master/SimpleAjaxUploader.js#L2002)</strike>:

```
'position' : 'absolute',
```

Alternatively: the issue does not appear to be present in Firefox. At any rate, I'll try to have a fix pushed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked on Chrome and you're right about the button not working. It is a problem with the [Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), unfortunately each browser has its own implementation.

Basically the outer `div` is preventing the click events from reaching the inner `input`.

My suggestion would be to use a custom button or to restyle the current one (I've found that if you remove the `position` property from the outer `div` it will work again. Consider that many properties can cause stacking context problems: position, transform, opacity, z-index. Try adding/removing/modifying some of them, in the outer `div` and in the inner `input`).

Anyway, it is guaranteed to be a style problem and not a JavaScript problem.